# Cannot find Account/Authorize when MVC Web App

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, iis

I have an MVC app having the following default routing map:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
    defaults: new {controller = "Startup", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

As long as I deploy this site to the root of my IIS server (c:\inetpub\wwwroot) and create a new **website** within IIS, everything works just fine.

However if I create a directory within the wwwroot folder structure, deploy the same files there and instead of creating a website, I create an Application underneath the DefaultWebSite and point it to the subfolder where the files reside (c:\inetpub\wwwroot\MyApplication); when I launch the WebApplication that previous was configured as a website, I get the error "***The resource you are looking for has been removed, had its name changed, or is temporarily unavailable.***"

Requested URL: http://localhost:80/Account/Authorize?client_id=web&response_type=token&state=

Physical Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\Account\Authorize

So it would appear that my routing needs to be adjusted to reflect the location of the app is in a subdirectory under wwwroot and not in wwwroot where it is looking.

What provisions should be taken to ensure an MVC Web "Application" runs properly under a Parent website?

=================================

## UPDATED OBSERVATIONS

After considering a posted comment, I found a few more details of my issue may be noteworthy to mention.

1. My application is redirecting to the requested URL I posted by default, I am not doing it. In other words, if I open IIS, right-click my application under the DefaultWebSite and select browse; I am getting the incorrect URL. I don't ever recall having this issue with ASP.NET applications which suggests to me "routing" problem
2. If I alter the URL so that the Application Name precedes the Account/Authorize path I get redirected again to http://localhost/#access_token=&token_type=bearer&expires_in=1209600 and receive a blank content page that says "Beginning Execution" in the upper right hand corner. The title of the page says CORS Detection Script. Suggesting to me that my application possibly resides in a different domain that the default website??? Need some clarity on this though.
3. If I again precede the URL that landed me on the CORS Detection Script page with the Application Name, my page successfully loads as I'd expect

================================================

So again, I believe there are some adjustments required somewhere within my app (probably within the routing configuration) to compensate for the incorrect URL being generated by default.

Because if I setup the application as a website with all content at the root instead of a subdirectory, everything works.

Surely someone has seen this before

Answer (score 1):

When you're creating an application in a subfolder of your website, you're effectively only changing the scope of the process running your app (w3p.exe). You will still need to put the application name in the url, like this:

http://localhost:80/MyApplication/Account/Authorize?etc

Comment: My application is redirecting to URL I posted in the question, I am not doing it. But to your point, if I alter the URL as you've suggested then I get redirected to http://localhost/#access_token=<alongtokenkeyhere>&token_type=bearer&expires_in=1209600 and receive a blank content page that says "Beginning Execution" in the upper right hand corner. The title of the page says CORS Detection Script. I'm updating my question with the new information. Thanks